# Is provoking friend for bad things considered cheating?

Tags: allah

I was 15-16 years old back then. Another classmate of mine said something unpleasant about my friend. I told my friend to do the same thing with her as . That classmate is my friend as well. Though she did nothing wrong with me she was kinda bitchy. My friend made an insulting social media post about her. I didn’t tell her to make a social media post, some other friends of her suggested the idea to her. But i am guilty of what i did. Is it considered cheating?

Comment: Cheating in what context?

Answer (score -1):

Yep, it is considered Fitnah which is really bad. Repent and never do it again

Comment: This hardly answers the question. Please read [answer].